# Can we extract graphics from PDF as single vector SVG file?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I have a PDF which contains several figures. All these figures are vector images and hence they dont pixelate when I zoom. I want to use those images in my word document and then generate PDF out of my word document by saving it as PDF. When I snip the images from source PDF say by using Windows Snipping tool and then paste in my word document and finally save it as PDF, then those images pixelated when I zoom in the PDF, because when I snip, its snips the bitmap of the image. Is it possible to extract vector images from any give pdf as say SVG file, so that I can reuse it in my Word doc and PDF.

I also have adobe acrobat pro wherein I can edit PDF or select multiple graphics  object, but can I save them single SVG file?

[image]
Adobe Acrobat PRO DC

PS: I tried this online tool to extract images from [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3293881.3295783) paper. This paper contains multiple tables with background graphics on same page. The tool generates single SVG for single page with all tables. Their background graphics is stored separated as JPG file and is overlayed on table when I open corresponding SVG. This is not something really what I want as I cant copy paste the whole table with background graphics as vector.

Comment: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/extract-vector-graphic-pdf-47224.html : The Third Paragraph explains the way to do it via Adobe Acrobat (Sorry for the link earlier )

Comment: From the steps, it seems that adobe acrobat cant do it by itself. It requires Adobe illustrator.

Comment: Just to make clear what I meant earlier, in case it was misunderstood - Just below the paragraph meant for Illustrator, The article also provides steps for Adobe Acrobat - Did the steps not work?

Comment: From steps of Adobe Acrobat: "Click "Choose Page/Object Editor" and then in the resulting dialogue box navigate to any vector-editing program (such as Illustrator, Corel Draw or Inkscape) installed on your computer. Acrobat cannot edit the vector graphic directly, but it allows you to specify a vector-editing program on your computer to which it will be extracted."

Comment: @SaaranshGarg InkSpace did the trick. Small app, mere 90 MB of exe and 500 MB of installation space. Saved a lot of efforts with Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) for this.

Inkscape can import specific pages from PDF files and output various vector formats including svg.

You may have to use the "ungroup" or "break apart" tools to separate elements you do not want in your export before you can delete them.

Once ready you can use the "document properties" tool where there is a "fit canvas" item that will reduce the page size, and resultant export, to fit only the items you want rather than having a mostly empty A4 page with your item on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to fit canvas... and other stuff... To be precise to fit canvas to selected image, `open document properties (Ctrl+Shift+D) > Page > Page Size > Custom Size > Resize page to drawing or selection`.

Comment: I need some more information. I extracted the vector image as SVG. It was of 11 MB. I compressed it using online tool. But its 5 MB. MS Word seems to struggle with such a big file. Do you use latex / overleaf. Or there is some trick to make MS Word work with such large file?

Comment: I tend to delete as much unnecessary detail as I can and use emf or emz (compressed emf) format if I'm using word.

Comment: "Tend to delete as much unnecessary details"... manually by editing tags or by using some visual editor (like Inkscape or Illustrator)? Without affecting actual image? I just saved it as eps and the size is down to 380 KB. But realize I cannot include eps file in Word. So converted it back to emf using online tool, but the size is back to 11 MB. Inkscape doesnt allow to save it as emz? How you generate emz? What is your usual workflow / is there any tut for this? from pdf -> vector image that can be imported in word without making it struggle?

Comment: ... continued from large comment. I just tried to regenerate emf files. They are truning out to be very very big. VG of 2 MB is now EMF of 9 MB and SVG of 11 MB is now EMF of 60 MB. However, when I import them in Word, the overall word file size is down from 13 MB to 1.5 MB. Also word doesnt seem to struggle at all. Can you enlighten me if you have any insights why is this behavior?